C libusb - get the correct devices and data?
I'm learning C and how to use libusb to get the usbs connected to the machine. I wanted to filter the device list just for the usbs that are mass storage (exclude the keyboards, mouse, etc...) so I just have the usb device with file system. I am facing some issues at the moment of filtering devices and getting the correct device vendor and product.
I'm working and compiling on Linux, have installed apt install libusb-1-0.0-devand my code looks like this:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libusb.h>

int main()
{
    libusb_context *ctx = NULL;

    libusb_device **list;
    ssize_t count;

    if (libusb_init(&ctx) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error init\n");
        return 1;
    }

    count = libusb_get_device_list(ctx, &list);
    if (count < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error list\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (ssize_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        libusb_device *device = list[i];
        struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
        libusb_device_handle *handle = NULL;
        char vendor[256], product[256], serial[256];
        if (libusb_get_device_descriptor(device, &desc) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error reading\n");
            continue;
        }

        if (libusb_open(device, &handle) != LIBUSB_SUCCESS)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open\n");
            continue;
        }

        libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(handle, desc.iManufacturer, (unsigned char *)vendor, sizeof(vendor));
        libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(handle, desc.iProduct, (unsigned char *)product, sizeof(product));
        libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(handle, desc.iSerialNumber, (unsigned char *)serial, sizeof(serial));

        libusb_close(handle);
        printf("Device Descriptor:\n");
        printf("  Vendor:             %s\n", vendor);
        printf("  Product:             %s\n", product);
        printf("  Serial:             %s\n", serial);
        printf("  bDescriptorType:     %u\n", desc.bDescriptorType);
        printf("  bcdUSB:              %u\n", desc.bcdUSB);
        printf("  bDeviceClass:        %u\n", desc.bDeviceClass);
        printf("  bDeviceSubClass:     %u\n", desc.bDeviceSubClass);
        printf("  bDeviceProtocol:     %u\n", desc.bDeviceProtocol);
        printf("  bMaxPacketSize0:     %u\n", desc.bMaxPacketSize0);
        printf("  idVendor:            0x%04x\n", desc.idVendor);
        printf("  idProduct:           0x%04x\n", desc.idProduct);
        printf("  bcdDevice:           %u\n", desc.bcdDevice);
        printf("  iManufacturer:       %u\n", desc.iManufacturer);
        printf("  iProduct:            %u\n", desc.iProduct);
        printf("  iSerialNumber:       %u\n", desc.iSerialNumber);
        printf("  bNumConfigurations:  %u\n", desc.bNumConfigurations);
    }

    libusb_free_device_list(list, 1);
    libusb_exit(ctx);
    return 0;
}

At this point, I'm able to get the devices but don't know how to filter them just for usb mass storage (It also gets the keyboard, mouse or hubs, which I don't need) and how to get the correct vendor and product; the output of my connected usb looks from lsusb like this:
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
The output of my program for that usb is:
Device Descriptor:
  Vendor:             Logitech
  Product:             Mass Storage
  Serial:             30CCF020
  bDescriptorType:     1
  bcdUSB:              512
  bDeviceClass:        0
  bDeviceSubClass:     0
  bDeviceProtocol:     0
  bMaxPacketSize0:     64
  idVendor:            0x058f
  idProduct:           0x6387
  bcdDevice:           256
  iManufacturer:       1
  iProduct:            2
  iSerialNumber:       3
  bNumConfigurations:  1

But sometimes is:
Device Descriptor:
  Vendor:             Generic
  Product:             Mass Storage
  Serial:             30CCF020
  bDescriptorType:     1
  bcdUSB:              512
  bDeviceClass:        0
  bDeviceSubClass:     0
  bDeviceProtocol:     0
  bMaxPacketSize0:     64
  idVendor:            0x058f
  idProduct:           0x6387
  bcdDevice:           256
  iManufacturer:       1
  iProduct:            2
  iSerialNumber:       3
  bNumConfigurations:  1

My usb device is not Logitech and and sometimes it's detected as 'generic' (is a libsub problem or a missing driver?). How do I filter just by mass storage devices?

On Linux you can use libudev to explore the device tree created by the OS.  The libusbp project uses that to identify USB serial ports and you could probably do something similar for USB mass storage devices.  As for the USB string descriptor sometimes being wrong, I suspect that's a bug in your particular USB device's firmware.
